# Psycopg2 not installing on Mac M1

Tags: python, django, heroku, psycopg2

The problem is that `psycopg2` isn't installing inside a Virtual Env for a project running with Python and Django on a Mac M1.

Django-heroku is trying to install that dependency but is not working on M1.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to code on a VM